# JQuery fadeOut or hide not working after click on safari

Tags: jquery, safari

```
jQuery( "#bottomusermenu .link_item" ).click(function() {
  jQuery( "body" ).fadeOut( "slow");
});
```

Strange bug here, I want to create a cool fade out effect after clicking a tab switcher to replicate a native app. This code works perfectly on Chrome with both fadOut and hide but neither works on Safari. I have tried just

```
  jQuery( "body" ).fadeOut( "slow");
```

Alone and it's work but after click you don't see the fade out before transitioning to the new page/url. Chrome it works perfectly

This is safari on iOS and browser.

Answer (score 0):

Just guessing - maybe Safari follows the link and load the new page before the fade-animation is completed. For verification you could try

```
jQuery( "#bottomusermenu .link_item" ).click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  jQuery( "body" ).fadeOut( "slow");
});
```

Comment: You don't even see it start though. Yes it works if it does not follow the link, it has something to do with the link navigation for sure as it's a simple piece of jQuery.